# Can't install pear in windows 10 + laragon

Tags: php, pear, laragon

I'm tryin to install PEAR in W10 + Laragon ( php 7.2 ), and I get this error:

```
Beginning install...
Configuration written to C:\Windows\pear.ini...
Initialized registry...
Preparing to install...
installing phar://C:/laragon/bin/pear/go-pear.phar/PEAR/go-pear-tarballs/Archive_Tar-1.4.5.tar...
installing phar://C:/laragon/bin/pear/go-pear.phar/PEAR/go-pear-tarballs/Console_Getopt-1.4.2.tar...
installing phar://C:/laragon/bin/pear/go-pear.phar/PEAR/go-pear-tarballs/PEAR-1.10.8.tar...
installing phar://C:/laragon/bin/pear/go-pear.phar/PEAR/go-pear-tarballs/Structures_Graph-1.1.1.tar...
installing phar://C:/laragon/bin/pear/go-pear.phar/PEAR/go-pear-tarballs/XML_Util-1.4.3.tar...
installing PEAR-1.10.9.tar...

Warning: require_once(phar://go-pear.phar/PEAR/REST/13.php): failed to open stream: phar error: "PEAR/REST/13.php" is not a file in phar "go-pear.phar" in phar://C:/laragon/bin/pear/go-pear.phar/PEAR/Config.php on line 2067
```

I just downloaded go-pear.phar from : https://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar

And i follow some instructions in this tutorial:

https://youtu.be/b1v9nwVxjTg?t=1025

But, I allways get that error...

Any idea what can be wrong ?

Best Regards

Comment: Consider using Composer instead. All PEAR packages should have a copy in Packagist - for example, https://packagist.org/packages/pear/archive_tar. PEAR is likely to be deprecated in PHP 8.

Comment: thanks @ceejayoz, the thing is that this is a legacy that i have to do some maintenance ... so by now i'll need PEAR. Best Regards